# Is there a documentation of documentation syntax?

Tags: support, documentation

In order to put version condition we can use :

```
<!-- if version [lt 2.9] -->
...
<!-- end version if -->
```

I find this, editing existing post, but I did not find a list of supported features.

Is there such documentation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup! You can find it documented in [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#inline-versions), which is linked to from every editor (question mark->advanced help).

This particular topic can also be found linked from [the Flexible Versions topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions) in the help center.